# Android Crash: "java.lang.IllegalStateException - This mutex is not locked" in MutexImpl.unlock

Tags: android, kotlin, crash, mutex, kotlin-coroutines

I'm encountering a rather puzzling crash in my Android application and could use some assistance in figuring out the root cause and how to resolve it. The crash is accompanied by the following error message:

```
MutexImpl.unlock
java.lang.IllegalStateException - This mutex is not locked
kotlinx.coroutines.sync - Mutex.kt:213
```

Here's a bit more context about my setup:

- I'm developing an Android application using Kotlin.
- The crash doesn't
  occur consistently, making it difficult to pinpoint the exact
  scenario that triggers it.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue before or has some insights into why this might be happening, I'd greatly appreciate your help

Comment: Do you use mutexes in your code? You need to look for the stack trace of the error to pinpoint where exactly the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is throwed by Mutex.unlock(owner: Any? = null) method.
kotlinx.coroutines.sync.MutexImpl#unlock

```
 /**
 * Unlocks this mutex. Throws [IllegalStateException] if invoked on a mutex that is not locked or
 * was locked with a different owner token (by identity).
 *
 * @param owner Optional owner token for debugging. When `owner` is specified (non-null value) and this mutex
 *        was locked with the different token (by identity), this function throws [IllegalStateException].
 */
public fun unlock(owner: Any? = null)
```

So you should check all of mutex that use unlock, And recommend replace call the mutex.lock or unlock method directly with mutex.withLock method or check mutex.isLocked/holdsLock before call unlock.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mutex and haven't intentionally used it. It's possible that it's being used indirectly through some other mechanism. Do you have any suggestions on what I should investigate or look for? @Lowae